# Jest snapshots having color shift using storybook backgrounds

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, snapshot, storybook

I have a project that uses Storybook backgrounds addon to test light and dark mode components. But some dark mode tests seem to be failing despite the component looking identical. I dived deeper and when I pick the background color with a color picker in paint all of the tests have a different shade of black. Though it has been set to #000000 for 'dark' mode the background colors in the result is often rgb(2, 2, 2) or rgb(4, 4, 4) or rgb(8, 8, 8).

This is causing the tests to fail. And this seems to be completely random. Once I run the test some component snapshot has rgb(2,2,2) I change nothing and run it again and its rgb(8, 8, 8).

What is causing this cause it seems to be rendering perfectly in the browser storybook.

Here's the snippets

**.storybook/preview.js**

```js
import { setCompodocJson } from "@storybook/addon-docs/angular";
import docJson from "../documentation.json";
setCompodocJson(docJson);

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  docs: { inlineStories: true },
  design: {
    type: 'figma',
    // a personal access token can be generated on figma https://www.figma.com/developers/api#access-tokens
    accessToken: '<insert-your-figma-token-here>',
  },
  backgrounds: {
    default: 'light',
    values: [
      {
        name: 'light',
        value: '#ffffff',
      },
      {
        name: 'dark',
        value: '#000000',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

**.storybook/main.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-backgrounds",
    'storybook-addon-designs',
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/angular",
  "core": {
    "builder": "@storybook/builder-webpack5"
  },

   managerWebpack: (config, options) => {
    options.cache.set = () => Promise.resolve();
    return config;
  },
}
```

test.stories.js

```js
export const smallDarkRadioButton = Template.bind({})
smallDarkRadioButton.parameters = { backgrounds: { default: 'dark' } }
smallDarkRadioButton.args = {
    size: 'small',
    disabled: false,
    label: 'Small Radio Button',
    rdName: 'rdSmall',
    rdValue: 'Small Radio Button',
    checked: false,
    colorTheme: 'dark'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `page.screenshot()` to snap the image, this option will make it omit the background of the Story from the snapshot, hence stop failing on it:

```
const image = await page.screenshot({ omitBackground: true });
```

Don't forget to rebuild Storybook after this change.

Comment: If you're not using `page.screenshot()`, follow image snapshots recipe here: https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/test-runner#image-snapshot-recipe